# How to detect USB port on android?

Tags: android, usb, tablet

I'm developing printer application based on Android phonegap.Now i hard coded the data and sent it to the printer.It's working fine.But my requirement is data will come on from the taxi meter via USB cable.How can i detect that data coming port?

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely looking for is the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). Keep in mind the following:

> **Note:** Accessory mode is ultimately dependent on the device's hardware
>   and not all devices will support accessory mode. Devices that support
>   accessory mode can be filtered using a `<uses-feature>` element in
>   your corresponding application's Android manifest. For more
>   information, see the [USB
>   Accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html#manifest)
>   Developer Guide.

Another thing to be aware of is that if your other device *does not* support Accessory mode, you can either *make* it support accessory mode (you haven't mentioned if this a homebrew or commercial device), or root your Android device and then pretty much anything is possible.